# Thread safety of final field

Tags: java, multithreading, thread-safety

Let's say I have a JavaBean *User* that's updated from another thread like this:

```
public class A {

    private final User user;

    public A(User user) {
        this.user = user;
    }

    public void aMethod() {
        Thread thread = new Thread(new Runnable() {

            @Override
            public void run() {
                ...a long running task..
                user.setSomething(something);
            }

        });
        t.start();
        t.join();
    }

    public void anotherMethod() {
        GUIHandler.showOnGuiSomehow(user);
    }
}
```

Is this code thread safe? I mean, when the thread that created A instance and called A.aMethod reads user fields, does it see user in the fresh state? How to do it in appropriate thread safe manner?

Note that I can't modify the user class and I don't know if it's thread safe itself.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> Is this code thread safe? ... does it see user in the fresh state?

Not especially - the fact that `user` is final in your code makes almost no difference to thread safety other than the fact that it cannot be replaced.

The bit that should change is the instance variable that is set by `setSomething`. It should be marked as `volatile`.

```
class User {
  // Marked `volatile` to ensure all writes are visible to other threads.
  volatile String something;

  public void setSomething(String something) {
    this.something = something;
  }

}
```

If however (as you suggest) you do not have access to the `User` class, you must then perform a synchronization that creates a memory barrier. In its simplest form you could surround your access to the `user` with a `synchronized` access.

```
synchronized (user) {
  user.setSomething(something);
}
```

---

Added :- It turns out (see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16711748/823393)) that this can actually be done like this:

```
volatile int barrier = 0;
...
user.setSomething(something);
// Forces **all** cached variable to be flushed.
barrier += 1;
```

Comment: Let's say I can't modify the User class in any way.

Comment: @Behnil - Answer extended.

Answer (score 4):

marking field as `final` just means that *reference* cannot be changed. It means nothing about thread safity of class `User`. If methods of this class that access fields are synchronized (or use other synchronization technique) it is thread safe. Otherwise it is not.

Answer (score 0):

final only makes the reference not re-assignable, but if the reference points to a mutable class, you can still alter the state inside that object, which causes thead-unsafe.

Your code is only thread safe if the User class is immutable, I.e. all properties of User cannot be altered outside the object, all references in the class point to other immutable class.

If it is not case, then you have to properly synchronize its methods to make it thread safe.

Answer (score 0):

> Note that I can't modify the user class and I don't know if it's thread safe itself.

You have to synchronize your access when accessing the User object.
You can for example use the User object to synchronize, so just wrap every access on the user object with something like:

```
synchronized(user) {
  // access some method of the user object
}
```

That assumes that the user object is only accessed in your threads asynchronously. Also keep the synchronized blocks short.

You could also build a threadsafe wrapper around the user object. I would suggest that if you have a lot of different calls, the code gets cleaner and better to read that way.

good luck!

Answer (score 0):

Concerning threading, `final`fields are just guaranteed to be consistent in case of [constructor escape](http://jeremymanson.blogspot.fr/2008/07/immutability-in-java-part-2.html), since the [JSR-133](http://www.cs.umd.edu/~pugh/java/memoryModel/jsr-133-faq.html#finalRight) about Memory Barrier mechanism:

> The values for an object's final fields are set in its constructor.
>   Assuming the object is constructed "correctly", once an object is
>   constructed, the values assigned to the final fields in the
>   constructor will be visible to all other threads without
>   synchronization.                                                                                                                                                                           In addition, the visible values for any other object
>   or array referenced by those final fields will be at least as
>   up-to-date as the final fields. What does it mean for an object to be
>   properly constructed? It simply means that no reference to the object
>   being constructed is allowed to "escape" during construction. (See
>   Safe Construction Techniques for examples.)  In other words, do not
>   place a reference to the object being constructed anywhere where
>   another thread might be able to see it; do not assign it to a static
>   field, do not register it as a listener with any other object, and so
>   on. These tasks should be done after the constructor completes, not in
>   the constructor.

However, **nothing ensures automatic thread-safety about any final fields in the remaining object's life (meaning after wrapping class's constructor execution).**. Indeed, immutability in Java is a pure misnomer:

> Now, in common parlance, immutability means "does not change".
>   Immutability doesn't mean "does not change" in Java. It means "is
>   transitively reachable from a final field, has not changed since the
>   final field was set, and a reference to the object containing the
>   final field did not escape the constructor".

Comment: I don't think the given definition for immutability is quite right. If a reference to an object was stored in a `final` field, but some other reference to that object also exists, I don't think the object will be "immutable" from the point of view of any reference *which has not been read or copied from a `final` field*.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, this is safe. See

[Java Language Specification (Java 8) Chapter 17.4.4](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-17.html#jls-17.4.4):

> The final action in a thread T1 synchronizes-with any action in another thread T2 that detects that T1 has terminated.
>
> T2 may accomplish this by calling T1.isAlive() or T1.join().

Put this together with [17.4.5. Happens-before Order](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-17.html#jls-17.4.5):

> Two actions can be ordered by a happens-before relationship. If one action happens-before another, then the first is visible to and ordered before the second. [..] If an action x synchronizes-with a following action y, then we also have hb(x, y).

So after you call `t.join();` in your code you will see the updated changes. Since "the thread that created A instance and called A.aMethod" can impossibly read the value after calling `aMethod` and before `t.join` is called (because it is busy with method `aMethod`), this is safe.